# Log into a website using Requests module in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new in Python and web scraping, but I keep learning. I have managed to get some exciting results using BeautifulSoup and Requests libraries and my next goal is to log into a website that allows remote access to my heating system to do some web scraping and maybe extend its capabilities further.

Unfortunately, I got stuck. I have used Mozilla's  Web Dev Tools to see the url that the form posts to, and the name attributes of the username and password fields. The webpage url is https://emodul.pl/login and the Request payload looks as follows:

```
{"username":"my_username","password":"my_password","rememberMe":false,"languageId":"en","remote":false}
```

I am using requests.Session() instance to make a post request to the login url and using the above-mentioned payload:

```
import requests

url = 'https://emodul.pl/login'
payload = {'username':'my_username','password':'my_password','rememberMe':False,'languageId':'en','remote':False}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(p.text)
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting the "error":"Sorry, something went wrong. Try again." response.

Any advice will be much appreciated.